# Qt - resolve two sequential calls on a slot and perform action only once

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, signals-slots, qt-signals

I have a `CodeEditor` class which inherits from `QPlainTextEdit`. This class has to emit requests when `textCursor()`'s position or selection changes. The thing is, I don't want 2 calls to `assembleIntellisenseRequest` and `pickListSortRequest` signals when both `cursorPositionChanged` and `selectionChanged` is emitted. I solved this with adding `bool update_` member to `CodeEditor`, which is set to `true` in constructor. 500ms delay is just for clarity.

```
void CodeEditor::makeConnections()
{
    auto updateRequest = [this]()
    {
        if(update_ && !textCursor().hasSelection())
        {
            update_ = false;
            QTimer::singleShot(500, [this]() { update_ = true; });

            emit assembleIntellisenseRequest(textCursor().blockNumber());
            emit pickListSortRequest(textCursor().positionInBlock());
        }
    };

    connect(this, &CodeEditor::cursorPositionChanged, updateRequest);
    connect(this, &CodeEditor::selectionChanged, updateRequest);
}
```

Is there any better way to accomplish this? Also, why was in this case, when lambda captures by reference `this1:` printout not equal to `this:`? It was silent, I just knew, that `update_` is still `false`.

```
auto updateRequest = [this]()
{
    cout << "this: " << this << endl;

    if(update_ && !textCursor().hasSelection())
    {
        update_ = false;
        QTimer::singleShot(500, [&]()
        {
            cout << "this1: " << this << endl;
            update_ = true;
        });

        emit assembleIntellisenseRequest(textCursor().blockNumber());
        emit pickListSortRequest(textCursor().positionInBlock());
    }
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try next code to understand problems with "this": `qobject_cast<QObject *>(this)->metaObject()->className()`. Or even better `typeid( *this ).name()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply next pattern to your code:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
private slots:
  void updateRequest();  

private:
  QTimer *_timer;
  CodeEditor *_editor;
};


MyClass::MyClass()
{
  // Init members
  // ...
  _timer->setSingleShot( true );
  _timer->setInterval( 0 );

  connect( _editor, &CodeEditor:: cursorPositionChanged, _timer, &QTimer::start);
  connect( _editor, &CodeEditor:: selectionChanged, _timer, &QTimer::start);
  connect( _timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyClass::updateRequest );
}
```

In this solution, timer is a "proxy for signals". Each time signal is emited timer will start immedeately (when flow will return to an event loop). Each emitting of signal will call `QTimer::start` slot. But all calls of `start` will place only one call of `timeout` signal to event queue. So, when control flow will return to event loop, your `updateRequest` slot will be called only once, even if a lot of signals were emited.

`QTimer` is a "Qt way" to replace your `update_` variable, without any timeouts.

Comment: Thank you for this neat solution, do you have any idea on what was the problem with that reference-capturing lambda?

Comment: No, I don't. We just moved from Cpp03 to Cpp14, so I have only basic knowledge about lambdas. Without Qt-specific things.